# Tortoise Svn reintegrate branch into trunk

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, conflict, reintegration

I tried to reintegrate my branch back into the trunk according to the answers of this:
[Tortoisesvn Subversion 1.8 - merge - no more reintegrate a branch option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444634/tortoisesvn-subversion-1-8-merge-no-more-reintegrate-a-branch-option)

But im getting Tree Conflicts.

This is what i have done so far:
I synchronized my branch with "Merge a range of revision", specific range (the revision of the last sync to HEAD). So I have all features of the Trunk in my Branch!

Then i performed another update on the trunk.
Rightclick on trunk folder->Merge->Merge a range of revision.
Entered URL of my branch.
Selected "all revisions".
Clicked "next" and then only "test merge".

among other things, this messages came:

```
Tree conflict: ...\trunk\.classpath  
Tree conflict: ...\trunk\.project  
Tree conflict: ...\trunk\lib  

Added: ...\trunk\lib\xy.jar
```

for all files in the folder (which already do exist in both)

The same for the other folders.

finally this:

```
Error: One or more conflicts were produced while merging r3347:3686 into
```

Whats the Problem?

Comment: A google search on `Tree conflict` should give you the answer.

Comment: show `svn ls -R` for trunk and branch

Comment: There are many possibilities, but you have probably created files under the same name in both branch and trunk. If you have only created directories, there is not so much to worry about, otherwise you will need to examine the duplicate files by hand. It is important to try to understand what you are doing: read the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

> Whats the Problem?

Problem

> I synchronized my branch with "Merge a range of revision", specific range

- Not needed anymore with 1.8+, performed in bad style - manual defining of range is *mauvais ton* after implementing mergeinfo in SVN 1.6

Try `svn diff --git` for trunk and branch and check output

Comment: I tried to to the Synchronisation with "all revisions" selected, but i received pretty much the same error messages, as i do now.
Thats why i did it after some research of (maybe outdated?) tutorials with the specific range.
When i check the diff of the trunk and the branch im not getting the files, which cause the error messages. Only the things which i changed on the branch, so just the way it has to be.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes I has similar conflicts when try reintegrate feature branch to trunk. This problem appeared in Subversion 1.8 with new symmetric merge algorithm.

I do not dig into problem too deep. I just use option on last page 'Reintegrate merge (old style)' and it is works.

Also I found that in some cases revert conflicts and merge again also solves problem.

So, try revert all changes and merge again. If it does not help - revert and use 'old style' reintegration option.

Comment: You would do better to try to understand what the conflicts mean: you may have been lucky so far, but you risk losing changes if you revert everything.

Comment: I never merge into 'dirty' working copy, so revert always revert only merge result.

Comment: So are you saying that results of the same merge command into an unmodified WC of the same revision from a repository in the same state gives unpredictable results?

Comment: I expirience this couple of times. I don't known what was reason (may be some my unnoticed actions). Though second time it was working correctly. I think it somehow related to SVN 1.8 feature - auto detection of reintegrate merge, because of unexpected conflicts which was look like merge synced revisions back to trunk.